# Unlocked Packages - Install using URL

Tags: unlocked-package

Is it possible to distribute an unlocked package using an installation URL?

Intent is to install the package into a different production org. (assuming the organization has multiple orgs)

Comment: Distribute to who? Unlocked are for internal users in a single org is that what you mean?

Comment: @user2451 -  Yes distribute to internal users across multiple salesforce orgs , in a company

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://sfdc-db-gmail.github.io/unlocked-packages/faq-unlocked-pkgs.html#pkg-install) is how to install via UI or CLI which includes:

**Salesforce UI**

By appending the following to the browser URL: packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=<04t id>

The 04t is the package version ID. This represents the version of the package to install. The 04t ID is returned when the force:package:version:create CLI command returns successfully. You can use force:package:version:list command to get a list of package versions associated with a package.

Comment: You should include the essential content of the link in this answer. While it was obviously useful to the OP, future visitors may find a dead link and no useful information. Please [edit] your answer to make it useful. Read [answer] for what we expect in useful answers.